# IIS 7.5 - Website needs restarting every morning

Tags: umbraco, iis-7.5

I have an Umbraco website that I have to restart every morning in order for the users to be able to publish content.  Is there any solutions available that will help me get around doing this each morning?

Comment: You've no idea why it's crashing or grinding to a halt? Nothing in the event log, Umbraco database, nothing wrong with any of the system performance views, database connections, etc.?

Comment: have you tried using the WarmUp feature of the IIS 7.5?

Comment: @Turek: Can't add something that is currently in Beta to a live production box unfortunately.

Comment: Howabout setting the recycling of the right Application Pool? The AppPool properties, "Recycle worker processes at the following times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Document why do you "have to" restart IIS every morning

- like the web app can't re-establish connection with SQL
- or one process gets so huge that it's obvious it's leaking
- or one process heats up with huge CPU usage and IIS keeps dropping requests
- etc. etc. have to check log files, EventLog, SQL Server has it's own log

2 - Document usage patters of the site

- like does it sit idle for 8-10 h or is busy all night

  - if it's busy then log files (including IIS log) will provide some info on when a problem started
  - if it's idle for a long time, check that AppPool for the site has automatic recycling of worker process set say after 1h of inactivity - you can also set diferent recycling tactics
  - if it's SQL connection after along idle period - Kerberos ticket   for the account expired.

    - you do have a domain account under which that AppPool runs I hope
  - to fix that, look at DB connection string (normally in web.config) and check MSDN for params
  - or bring up a new web site or app that's going to keep pinging a web method which will just do a little query ( like a count on some table) and return the result as a kind of admin heartbeat -- this helps only if you acsually see SQL connection issue

3 - Check if you have multiple sites / web apps running on the server

- that each has it's own AppPool and that they run under a domain account
- that each app has it's own, separate folder for logs and any other writable files
- that each AppPool has recycling tactics that's good for actual usage pattern
- needs different recycling tactics if it's busy all the time
- ask sor some mininal kind of heartbeat web service to be developed and pinged for ops needs

  - running as part of each web app and using the same SQL connection
  - if you don't have the budget for this raise some hell

    - makes you feel good  :-)